# How do I do non constant acceleration questions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, drag

Okay, so there is a type of question that keeps coming up in past papers and I can't seem to crack it. The one I'm doing now is:

> A skier initially travelling at $50~\text{m/s}$ along a frictionless horizontal surface is exposed to a headwind, which creates a drag force on the skier equal to $bv^2$
>   where $b = 0.2 ~\text{kg/m}$
>   d) Find an expression for the velocity of the skier as a function of the time travelled on 
>   this surface, $v(t)$

Could someone please show me how to do this? I can do calculus fine, but I can't seem to apply it to mechanics, and none of the past papers come with worked solutions, only numerical answers.

Comment: Integrate, integrate, integrate.

Comment: I know that, but how and with respect to what? It's not just a direct integration as the velocity is not constant with respect to time.

Comment: You know the acceleration, because you know the initial velocity, right? Do you know how to get the velocity from the acceleration?

Comment: Set up differential equation applying Newtons laws and solve the differential equation.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. There are two ways I see of doing that. F=ma=bv^2 so that a=(bv^2)/m, or a = b(dx/dt)^2/m which I cant integrate. Or, force x time = momentum, so that  F= mv/t = bv^2 then cancel v and integrate. But that gives the wrong answer

Comment: Please, if it's that easy for you, could you just spell it out for me? This exact question has come up on 2 out of 3 past papers now and there are no worked examples of this in the book, so I just don't know how to do it

Answer (score 3):

You solve problems like this by writing down the differential equation that describes the motion, and indeed you did get the correct equation in your comment:

$$ a = -\frac{b}{m}v^2 $$

All you need is to note that $a = dv/dt$, so you get:

$$ \frac{dv}{dt} = -\frac{b}{m}v^2 $$

If you haven't seen an equation like this before it looks difficult because you have $v$ on the right hand side instead of just $t$. The trick is to rearrange the equation to get:

$$ \frac{dv}{v^2} = -\frac{b}{m}dt $$

Then integrate both sides:

$$ \int\frac{dv}{v^2} = -\int\frac{b}{m}dt $$